# What happens to the notion of semantic entailment in logics other than boolean?

Tags: logic

Suppose we have a logic with three or more truth values, how can we deal with semantic entailment then?

From what I understand a set of statements A, semantically entails B if B cannot be false if all in A are true.
But this assumes we are dealing in a 2-valued logic.

I'm curious if there's a generalised concept of entailment, possibly even syntactic for an arbitrary logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In multi-valued logics there is still an ordering on the truth values. A statement $A$ entails a statement $B$ if $A$ is stronger than $B$ under this ordering (usually written $A \le B$). (Typically in such logics you can't view assumptions as a set, you have to treat them as a multiset, because $A \land A$ might be a stronger statement than $A$. Hence I'm replacing your set of assumption $A$ by a single assumption $A$ that is the conjunction of a multiset of assumptions.) [Fuzzy logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic), where the truth values are real numbers is a good example of such a logic. Multi-valued logics of this kind often don't admit the law of contraction: $A \to A \land A$ is not admissible.

Comment: To be fair, it's worth noting that many multi-valued logics (most?) *do* admit contraction.

Comment: I don't know about "most", but I have corrected my unintended statement that contraction is not admissible in any multi-valued logic. Thanks for pointing that out.